# Numba slower than python?

Tags: python, jit, numba

I'm really new to `numba` so I don't really understand why this happens. I'm running `njit` on a the bottleneck function of my program (Ising model) and it does slow it.

My function is :

```
@nb.njit#(nb.types.int64[:](nb.types.int64, nb.types.float64[:], nb.types.int64[:], nb.types.int64[:]))
def heat_bath_mcs(size, Z, s, neighbors):
    for step in range(size):
        choice = int(size*np.random.random())
        energy_variation = (s[neighbors[4*choice]]+s[neighbors[4*choice+1]]
                            + s[neighbors[4*choice+2]]+s[neighbors[4*choice+3]])
        if np.random.random() < 1.0/(1.0+Z[int(energy_variation*0.5)+2]):
            s[choice] = +1
        else:
            s[choice] = -1
    return s
```

`size` is an integer, `s` and `neighbors` are 2 python lists of length `size` both with integer values and `Z` a list of length 4 and float values.

Where I tried to infer the types but it gives this error(just using what's after # in the first code):

> TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) int64,
>   reflected list(float64), reflected list(int64), reflectedlist(int64)

If I print out the `numba` types before each call of the function I get:

```
print(nb.typeof(size),nb.typeof(Z),nb.typeof(s),nb.typeof(neighbors))
```

Results in:

```
int64 reflected list(float64) reflected list(int64) reflected list(int64)
```

So my question is, why does that happen? I guess I'm doing something wrong so how can I improve my code to speed it up?

Comment: You've got a bunch of *lists*. Numba is designed for NumPy *arrays*. List support is there for utility, not performance.

Comment: Completly right, I changed them all by numpy arrays and it works properly now.